# SqlDataReader - GetStream vs GetBytes on (n)varchar vs v (n)varchar(max) or for xml / for json

Tags: c#, sql-server, stream, sqldatareader

I've been working on a way to provide access to large SQL results as a stream, particularly when the query uses the for json or for xml clause.

I noticed that when the query returns json or xml the `SqlDataReader` does not allow use of the `GetStream()` method, which is expected as per the documentation:

> 'Invalid attempt to GetStream on column 'c'. The GetStream function can only be used on columns of type Binary, Image, Udt or VarBinary.'

However, it *does* allow use of `GetBytes()`.

The behaviour is the same when the returned data is `varchar(max)` or `nvarchar(max)`. `GetStream()` won't work, but `GetBytes()` will.

With a regular, length-limited `varchar` or `nvarchar` column, neither `GetStream` nor `GetBytes` are permitted.

Being able to call `GetBytes` means I have been able to build a custom `SqlTextStream : Stream` class fairly easily, with the proviso that when reading from `nvarchar` it's probably best to read bytes in multiples of two so as not to tear characters in half.

I looked at the information provided by `SqlDataReader.GetColumnSchema()`, but found no obvious reason why `GetBytes` is permitted against `n/varchar(max)` results. I might have missed something, but the `GetColumnSchema` output seems the same for regular or (max) character data with the exception of the length.

Does anyone know why `GetBytes` is permitted against `n/varchar(max)` columns? Do you think it is safe to rely on `GetBytes` being permitted?

Here's some simple test code:

```
public void Test()
{
    var cmd1 = "select c = 'getbytes permitted here' for json path";
    var cmd2 = "select c = cast('getbytes also permitted here' as nvarchar(max))";
    var cmd3 = "select c = cast('getbytes not permitted here' as nvarchar(32))";

    using (var con = new SqlConnection("data source=theDB; initial catalog=playground; integrated security=SSPI"))
        // switch between cmd1, cmd2 and cmd3 to see the different behaviour.
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(cmd1, con))
        {
            con.Open();

            using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
            {
                var o = rdr.GetColumnSchema();
                var buffer = new byte[128];
                rdr.Read();
                //System.IO.Stream s = rdr.GetStream(0); this is never permitted
                rdr.GetBytes(0, 0, buffer, 0, buffer.Length); // this is permitted for cmd1 and cmd2
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: can you clarify what it meant by the term `wrap up`?  what is the motivation here? is is performance?  please clarify your question...

Comment: I think this is an interesting - but possibly unanswerable - question; if anything, it prompts the question of "what encoding is that?"; I'd have thought `GetChars` and a `TextReader` would have been a more reliable API to implement here...

Comment: Changed "wrap up" to "provide acess to".

The motivation is performance, yeah. I started down this road when I was looking at pushing streams to httpClients via PushStreamContent, probably with a GZipStream in the middle. But I figured I might as well decouple the data access stream returning code from that, so I created a data access class which derives from stream. I figure it might be useful in other scenarios too.

Comment: Marc - Yeah, GetChars or GetTextReader will certainly work even if the result is not a (max) type, but since those will get char[], not byte[], a conversion would need to be performed to expose the result as a Stream. Not awful, and I do have a `Stream.Read()` implementation which does that - that was my first approach actually. But I got curious and started exploring options, and that's how I came across this behaviour.

Comment: @allmhuran - `char[]` would be more natural. By the time the client database driver is delivering results up to ADO.Net, I'm fairly certain any text will have been processed to be UTF-16.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever When using "for json" or "for xml" in SQL server it will come through as nvarchar anyway, so you're right. And when it comes out to .net it's certainly a string (or char[] if you like), which seems natural. The only problem with that is that streams are byte[], not char[], so any library code or other functionality which manages memory efficient via streams won't work. 

I suppose one could take the `TextReader` provided by `GetTextReader`, cast it to a `StreamReader` and get the `BaseStream`, but that seems less safe than creating my own stream class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This is the underlying code for [GetBytes](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/fx/src/data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlDataReader.cs,1504) (method starts on line 1504, but the fragment below starts on line 1510):

   ```cs
           // don't allow get bytes on non-long or non-binary columns
           MetaType mt = _metaData[i].metaType;
           if (!(mt.IsLong || mt.IsBinType) || (SqlDbType.Xml == mt.SqlDbType)) {
               throw SQL.NonBlobColumn(_metaData[i].column);
           }
   ```
2. The doc for [SqlDataReader.GetBytes(Int32, Int64, Byte[], Int32, Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getbytes#remarks) states:

   > No conversions are performed; therefore, the data retrieved must already be a byte array.
3. This difference in functionality and behavior is most likely due to how the data is stored internally within SQL Server. Which is why *true* XML is treated differently, even though it's a blob type: there is a special SqlXml binary format that is optimized by reducing tags and attributes into a dictionary to reduce bloat from duplication/repetition (and some other efficiencies). The reason your tests show the same behavior for `FOR JSON` and `FOR XML` should be that they both return `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, *but* doing `FOR XML, TYPE` returns *true* XML in the SqlXml format.